# How to create a striped progress bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I need your help to create a striped progressbar without restricting the height of it.

I already have a stripped progressbar, but when the height is too big, the strips looks very bad and i can't find a way to fix that.

Here is my current style :

```
    <Style x:Key="NormalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="7" />
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    Background="{DynamicResource LPercentBackground1Color}" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border x:Name="DiagonalDecorator" Width="5000">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Fill"  Viewbox="0,0,1,1" Viewport="0,0,36,34" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                        <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource LPercentBackground2Color}" Geometry="M0,0 -18,0 -36,34 -18,34 Z" />
                                        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Here is a good bar but with a smallest height : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuWC1.jpg .
Here is my progressbar when it's too big : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWfxQ.jpg

Comment: *"when the width is too big, the strips looks very bad"* - can you explain what is "very bad"? I can't imagine how would that thing ever looks good at all.

Comment: The strips "resets", it stops the top strip to start a new one
As if two progressbar are stacked one on another (watch imgur for a better idea)

Comment: Do you mean too big `Height`? Can you show *correct* looking small one?

Comment: I did meant height ahah thanks for the correction. I added the good bar in the post. Here is the link anyway : https://imgur.com/oieZqBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to limit `Height`, then one possibility is to scale drawing.

Feel free to criticize all the ugliness ;)

You will need a converter to convert actual width/height into scale factor:

```
public class MyConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        (double)value / double.Parse((string)parameter);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

In xaml you have to bind scale transform to parent `Border` size:

```
<Border x:Name="DiagonalDecorator">
    <Border.Background>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile"
                      Viewport="0,0,33,33"
                      ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, ConverterParameter=1000, Converter={local:MyConverter}}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, ConverterParameter=32, Converter={local:MyConverter}}" />
            </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black"
                                 Geometry="M0,0 -18,0 -36,34 -18,34 Z" />
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

If you don't want x scale, then set `ScaleX="1"` or some other constant factor.

Play with converter parameters until you are happy with what you see. Putting above border into blank window will produce this:

[image]

Comment: I admit it's those stripes are probably not the prettiest, but i needed those ahah
Thank you so much, i've been struggling for about 2-3 day with the stripes :)